# How to automatically transfer from student account to my regular email?

Tags: linux

I have a student account that professor sends all the emails, files and documents into that account. The account uses unix/linux. My question is that what is the unix command for forwarding automatically everything the professor sends in my student account is also goes to my regular eamil too?
Thanks a lot

Comment: what do you mean by `account uses unix/linux`? .... do you mean that the email server runs on a unix system? ... how would you run a command on the unix system?

Comment: I have a mac and from the terminal I connect to my account with the command ssh -X -Y -l csscxxxx edoras.sdsu.edu and then after enter my password I am in my account and professor created a file name Mailbox and in this mailbox he created a folder to name new and everything goes in this folder, what is the command to automatically send me everything in this folder to my regular email?

Comment: that makes sense now .... the professor copies files into your directory ... i thought that the files were emailed to you .... just google `unix how to email all files in a directory` .... i think that you should get a few hits

Comment: Yes, but need the command to transfer them all automatically to my email each time the professor sends files.

Comment: how do you plan to do that? ... will you keep your mac connected at all times? .... talk to the system admin and ask